# How to make a list containing checkboxes attached to object in a v-for directive switch state safely (W/O switching other checkboxes in the list)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to make a client-side-only todolist that uses VueJS (2.x). Here is my HTML:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>To-do List</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="app">
            <h1>To-do List</h1>
            <h2>Completed Tasks!</h2>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="item in complete">{{ item.description }}<input type="checkbox" :checked="item.done" @change="item.done = false"></li>
            </ul>
            <h2>Uncompleted Tasks!</h2>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="item in uncomplete">{{ item.description }}<input type="checkbox" :checked="item.done" @change="item.done = true"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Then in scripts/app.js I did this:

```js
    'use strict'
    
    let app = new Vue({
    
        el      : "#app",
        data    : {
            tasks: [
                { description: 'Say Hello', done: true },
                { description: 'Review Code', done: false },
                { description: 'Read Emails', done: false },
                { description: 'Reply to Emails', done: false },
                { description: 'Wash The Dishes', done: true },
                { description: 'Stop Working', done: true },
            ]
        },
        computed : {
            complete : function() {
                return this.tasks.filter(task => task.done === true);
            },
            uncomplete : function() {
                return this.tasks.filter(task => task.done === false);
            }
        }
    
    });
```

My issue is simple: when I change the state of a checkbox (checking it or unchecking it) in a given list, the checkbox that directly follows it switches state as well.

I can't figure out why this happens and how to fix it. If one can tell me **why** this happens (so that I don't have to come back here whenever I have a misbehaving `v-for`/switch-state) as well as how to fix it, that would be great!

Comment: What is the issue here ? Sorry I did not understand the question properly. Can you please help me in understanding the issue so that i can guide you.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal the issue is that whenever I check or uncheck a checkbox the following checkbox go to the same state even though I didn't check/unchecked it. But the issue was solved already by DengSihan below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. first of all. You'd better use `Function` in `data` instead of `Object`, or it may cause an update error.

Since `Function` is accepted only when used in a component definition.

```js
// wrong
data: {
    tasks: []
}

// correct
data() {
    return {
        task: []
    }
}
```

2. You may not change the `computed` attribute directly which only has a `Computed Getter` in default. If you want to handle the `computed` attribute, give a [`Computed Setter`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) to it.

```js
// wrong
computed: {
    complete(){
      return this.tasks.filter(task => task.done === true);
    },
}

// right
computed: {
    complete: {
        get() {
            return this.tasks.filter(task => task.done === true);
        },
        set(value) {
            this.task.forEach((task, index) => {
                let matched = value.find(({ description }) => description === task.description);
                if(matched) {
                    this.task[index] = matched;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

3. you can't bind the value via `v-for`, because vue2 can't recognize the changes in the array.

```html
<!-- wrong -->
<li
  v-for="item in complete">
  {{ item.description }}
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    :checked="item.done"
    @change="item.done = false">
</li>

<!-- correct -->
<li
  v-for="(item, index) in complete">
  {{ item.description }}
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    :checked="item.done"
    @change="complete[index].done = false">
</li>
```

---

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [
        { description: 'Say Hello', done: true },
        { description: 'Review Code', done: false },
        { description: 'Read Emails', done: false },
        { description: 'Reply to Emails', done: false },
        { description: 'Wash The Dishes', done: true },
        { description: 'Stop Working', done: true },
      ]
    };
  },
  computed : {
    complete: {
      get() {
        return this.tasks.filter(task => task.done === true);
      },
      set(value) {
        this.task.forEach((task, index) => {
          let matched = value.find(({ description }) => description === task.description);
          if(matched) {
              this.task[index] = matched;
          }
        });
      }
    },
    uncomplete: {
      get() {
        return this.tasks.filter(task => task.done === false);
      },
      set(value) {
        this.task.forEach((task, index) => {
          let matched = value.find(({ description }) => description === task.description);
          if(matched) {
              this.task[index] = matched;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>To-do List</h1>
  <h2>Completed Tasks!</h2>
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="(item, index) in complete">
      {{ item.description }}
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        v-model="complete[index].done">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Uncompleted Tasks!</h2>
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="(item, index) in uncomplete">
      {{ item.description }}
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        v-model="uncomplete[index].done">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```